# Getting helpful error messages on Windows 7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, windows-7, windows-error-reporting

During Windows XP development, if my application encountered an unhandled exception it would display an error message "X has encountered and error..." and give me the option to launch the debugger. Under Windows 7, all I get is a message that says "X has stopped working, Windows is checking for a solution".

I can no longer see any details of the error message and I'm not given the option to debug.

I'm using VS2005 and JIT debugging is enabled as far as I can tell.

Is there anyway to get back to the useful error messages of WinXP?

Edit: It is just a standard WinForms desktop application, requiring no special permissions to run.

Comment: IIRC it is an OS setting. Something along the lines of 'Disable error reporting'.

Comment: Did you try it with vs2008? If it is an elevated process then it cannot be JIT debugged with vs2005 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa964140.aspx#question20a

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you find the WER (Windows Error Reporting) settings useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638%28VS.85%29.aspx

Also, you can use this as a landing point to get in touch with WER:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513641%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Unfortunately I can't directly answer your question, but perhaps this can serve as a hint for further researching.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found an answer thanks to the comment from leppie.

1. Go to Control Panels->Action Center
2. Expand the Maintenance tab and select Settings under "Check for solutions to problem reports"
3. Change to "Never check for solutions"

Now when the error occurs there is a "Debug the program" option in the dialog.

Comment: If instead you set this option to "..ask me before checking..." you'll get an error dialog which also shows the exception code, etc.